# Tool for creating Vagrantfile

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting, vagrant

I am using Vagrant and I will be creating Vagrantfile's for a number of services. There is a lot of overlap in what I have to do to create those Vagrantfiles so I would like automate some of it.

Currently, I am putting special words in a Vagrantfile then using sed within a bash script. This seems a little awkward so how can I track down a better solution to this problem? Is this a 'templating' problem?
I suppose I'm trying to define the problem within software engineering practice.

Comment: vagrant is based on ruby and vagrantfile is actually a ruby script - I think using erb template could be an option and potentially re-used part of the vagrant code.

Comment: Your recommendation is to look at templating solutions in the literal-sense. That's worth investigating.

Comment: Frederic, add your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant is based on ruby and vagrantfile is actually a ruby script - I think using erb template could be an option and potentially re-used part of the vagrant code (for example look at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/templates/commands/init/Vagrantfile.erb)